# What is the short phrase meaning: "an accent dulled due to living abroad"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I lived abroad between the ages of 12-17 and due to regular "Could you repeat that?"s, my otherwise broad accent became more *posh* so that I was understood more easily.

Now people usually still know that I'm from Newcastle, UK, but often comment that my Geordie accent isn't particularly strong.

I'm sure there's a two-word phrase to describe this phenomenon, but I can't put my finger on it. I recall the phrase being armed-force-related since this might often happen to families posted abroad. Something similar to "army accent", but that doesn't sound quite right to me.

What is the short phrase meaning "an accent that has become less pronounced due to living abroad" please?

Answer (score 1):

"diluted"

A diluted accent would be one that was affected by its linguistic environment.

> The diluted accent will be some mix of your practiced British accent and your natural accent …
>   <sub>[englishforums.com](https://www.englishforums.com/English/PoorAccent/bpmpk/post.htm)</sub>

Discussion of challenges of keeping one's native accent while living abroad.  Cites "diluted accent "

Comment: Perhaps not the most authoritative  reference ever, but it  supports your answer :)

Comment: Yes.  The support was admittedly weak.  In my defense I was answering via my phone.  I'll edit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the phrase you have in mind, but I think if I said "He has a **softened** Geordie accent" most people would get the idea?